# Why is there space between the edge of the viewport and the edge of its elements, if the element's margins are set to 0px?

Tags: html, css, margin

Why aren't the top, left, and right edges of the red `p` element's border not directly aligned with the top, left, and right edges of the viewport?

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

p {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>p tag</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should become familiar with using your browser's developer tools to inspect the page. It's very easy to see [what styles are applied to an element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM93X.png).

Answer (score 1):

The document's `body` has a default margin of 8px. To solve your issue, set body's margin to 0px:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Tags don't have margins. Elements do. ;)

Answer (score -1):

It's because your browser user agent stylesheet by default has some spacing. Add the following code on top of your CSS:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image]

it should disable body margin like this, but use (*) sign cause other elements might also have

Comment: I don't recommend resetting margin and padding on every element in a site. That's a bit heavy-handed, especially with paragraphs and lists. Just apply it to the body element.

Comment: This would set *all*  margins to zero. Just compare tags like `p`, `li` and all headers (h1, h2 etc.) with and without that setting to see what basic layout it destroys...

Comment: @isherwood It will help you set some good precise sizes and spacing for your elements, most frontend developers do this to not get confused, it's up to you

Comment: "... most frontend developers do this ..." [citation needed]

Comment: @isherwood it's an example i said to not get confused. do whatever you want and you like :) what i said is not wrong and most websites use this when you know how much it helps let me know

Comment: at least if not for padding and margin, ```box-sizing: border-box;``` should be for all elements